# Get source of page from GeckoFX web browser component

Tags: c#, geckofx

Html code from `GeckoWebBrowser.Document.DocumentElement.InnerHtml` property differs from html downloaded from server because it is converted to DOM and there could be Javascript that changes document structure.

**How to get real page source?**

Answer (score 4):

There's a method for that:

```
GeckoWebBrowser.ViewSource();
```

or

```
GeckoWebBrowser.ViewSource(string url);
```

Opens a new window which contains the source code for the current (or specified) page. If you just want the text, try:

```
GeckoWebBrowser.Navigate("view-source:" + url);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a new way to fix your problem like that:

```
GeckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank")
```

`Me.Delay(1)` Make your function to wait 1 second here

```
GeckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("view-source:" + "YourUrl")
```

Comment: Don't add links of your blog/site. Those can be considered as spam and you might be punished.